# get table cell value using jquery on row click

Tags: jquery

i have simple table what i want is after click on specific row get the value of `incidentId` for that row and assign in to hidden empty variable.

my table

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead style="background-color: #F0F1F2">
       <tr>
         <th>Incident Id</th>
         <th>Party Name</th>
         <th>Max Rank</th>
         <th>Incident Description</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <c:forEach items="${incidents}" var="incident">
      <tr onclick="changeIncidentValue(this)">                                
         <td>${incident.incidentId}</td>
         <td>xxx</td>
         <td>${incident.partyNameMaxRank}</td>
         <td>${incident.incidentDesc}</td>
      </tr>
  </c:forEach>                           
 </tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" id="incidentId" value=""/>
```

js function

```
<script>
    function changeIncidentValue(incidentId){
        $('#incidentId').val(incidentId);
        console.log($('#incidentId').val());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: have u tried something??? where is your jquery code??

Comment: question updated

Comment: `<tr onclick="changeIncidentValue(${incident.incidentId})">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the `incidentId` instead of `this` to inline click handler

```
<tr onclick="changeIncidentValue(${incident.incidentId})">
```

instead of

```
<tr onclick="changeIncidentValue(this)">
```

---

Or, As you are passing `this`, use it with DOM traversal method to get the value from first TD element

```
function changeIncidentValue(elem){
    $('#incidentId').val($(elem).find('td:first').text());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find) and [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq) to get the `incidentId` from first column,

```
function changeIncidentValue(ths){
    $('#incidentId').val($(ths).find('td:eq(0)').text());
    consle.log($('#incidentId').val());
}
```

Or you can directly set incidentId's value onclick event like,

```
  <tr onclick="$('#incidentId').val(${incident.incidentId})">                                
     <td>${incident.incidentId}</td>
     <td>xxx</td>
     <td>${incident.partyNameMaxRank}</td>
     <td>${incident.incidentDesc}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Try this doesn't give any sense so explain your code how it works ?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/ew73yjaa/

jQuery

```
$('.t').on('click',function(){
  console.log($(this).find('td').first().text());
  $('#incidentId').val($(this).find('td').first().text());
})
```

HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead style="background-color: #F0F1F2">
   <tr>
     <th>Incident Id</th>
     <th>Party Name</th>
     <th>Max Rank</th>
     <th>Incident Description</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="t">                                
     <td>1</td>
     <td>xxx</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
  </tr>                  
</tbody>
</table>
<input id="incidentId" value=""/>
```